# How does the Ring of Jumping combine with Tabaxi Feline Agility?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, movement, racial-traits

The [Tabaxi racial trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/tabaxi#TabaxiTraits) "Feline Agility" (*Volo's Guide to Monsters*, p. 115) says:

> When you move on your turn in combat, you can double your speed until the end of the turn.

The [Ring of Jumping](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-jumping) (from the Basic Rules) says:

> While wearing this ring, you can cast the *jump* spell from it as a bonus action at will, but can target only yourself when you do so.

The [*jump*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/jump) spell (Basic Rules) says:

> [your] jump distance is tripled

How do those combine?

As a specific example, Tabitha the Tabaxi Bard, strength of 10, is 30 feet from, for instance, a hell hound (bad dog!). How could she use *jump* from the ring to get the jump on that damned dog?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, feel free to share your reasoning.  Is it a bad question in some way?

Answer (score 6):

Your speed and the distance you can jump are related, but separate.

## Base speed

[The basic rules define a creature's speed like this](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#Speed):

> Every character and monster has a speed, which is the distance in feet that the character or monster can walk in 1 round.

Other actions and features key off your speed to determine different modes of movement, or the way your movement works in combat. Most importantly, the description of [movement in combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition) states:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed.

## Base jumping distance

[The rules on jumping are provided here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#Jumping):

> Your Strength determines how far you can jump.
>
> ***Long Jump.*** When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet up to your Strength score if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only half that distance. **Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.**
>
> [...]
>
> ***High Jump.*** When you make a high jump, you leap into the air a number of feet equal to 3 + your Strength modifier if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing high jump, you can jump only half that distance. **Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.** In some circumstances, your DM might allow you to make a Strength (Athletics) check to jump higher than you normally can.

As you can see, jumping is not separate from movement; it uses your movement.

## The *jump* spell

The *jump* spell (and the *ring of jumping* that you can cast it from) doesn't affect your speed at all. It solely triples your jump distance. What that means is:

- Instead of a running long jump letting you horizontally jump [a number of feet equal to Strength score] (and half that if you make a standing jump), the *jump* spell lets you jump [3 times your Strength score] in feet with a running jump, or [1.5 times Strength score] for a standing jump.
- Instead of a running high jump letting you vertically jump [3 + Strength mod] feet into the air (and half that on a standing high jump), the *jump* spell lets you jump [3 * (3 + Strength mod)] feet up with a running jump, or [1.5 * (3 + Str mod)] feet with a standing jump.

Note that the spell does not affect your speed at all. Jeremy Crawford clarifies [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/04/29/what-happens-when-jump-gives-a-jump-distance-greater-than-walking-speed/) and [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/09/18/super-jump/) on Twitter that your jump distance is still limited by how far you can move (though you can take the [Dash](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Dash) action to increase your available movement for the turn).

## Feline Agility

This one's easy. It simply doubles your speed until the end of the turn. Nothing more, nothing less. Anything that keys off your speed, including the distance you can move in a turn, is now keying off your doubled speed until the end of the turn. (Note that the trait does specify that once you use it to double your speed, you can't use it again until you move 0 feet on one of your turns.)

## Tabitha the Tabaxi Bard, with *jump* and Feline Agility active

You specified this example:

> Tabitha the Tabaxi Bard, strength of 10, is 30 feet from, for instance, a hell hound

If she has a Strength score of 10, her running long jump distance would normally be 10 feet (i.e. with a running start of 10 feet before she jumps); with a standing long jump, she could only jump half that distance, for a total of 5 feet. No matter how far she jumps, it uses her movement to do so (in addition to any movement needed for the running start if applicable).

With the *jump* spell, her jump distance is tripled. She could now make a running long jump of 30 feet; however, she would need a running start of 10 feet before she jumps to get that far, using a total of 40 feet of movement. (Without a running start, she could only jump 15 feet.)

However, tabaxi have a regular walking speed of 30 feet, so normally she'd need to take the [Dash](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Dash) action (which adds an amount equal to your speed to your movement) in order to make a maximum-length running long jump. Thankfully, Tabaxi also have the Feline Agility trait, which allows them to choose to double their speed for one turn (and they can only use the ability to do so again after they spend a turn not using their movement).

By activating the Feline Agility trait, Tabitha has a speed of 60 feet for a turn; using her Ring of Jumping to cast *jump* on herself as a bonus action, her jump distance is tripled. She would thus be able to get a running start of 10 feet, jump a maximum of 30 feet (i.e. 3 * Str score), and still have 20 feet of movement *and* an action left on her turn to use as she wishes.

(That said, jumping across regular terrain doesn't really accomplish much, except maybe looking cool. She'd only really need to make that sort of horizontal jump to get over a crevasse/pit or environmental hazard.)

Comment: very helpful, esp. the part about combining with Feline Agility and the part about jumping across regular terrain doesn't make much difference.

Comment: In my experience, the usual reason for jumping is to get past small amounts of difficult terrain.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, you are looking for a Long Jump.

> **Long Jump**. When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet **up to** your Strength score if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only half that distance. Either way, **each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.**
>
> This rule assumes that the height of your jump doesn't matter, such as a jump across a stream or chasm. At your GM's option, you must succeed on a DC 10 Strength (Athletics) check to clear a low obstacle (no taller than a quarter of the jump's distance), such as a hedge or low wall. Otherwise, you hit it.
>
> When you land in difficult terrain, you must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity (Acrobatics) check to land on your feet. Otherwise, you land prone.

From that, let's check the beginning: if you move 10 ft before jumping, you can jump up to 10 ft. Without running, 5 ft. With the spell, you can, instead, jump up to 30 ft with running and 15 ft without running.

For you to be able to jump close to the hound, you would need to run 10 ft and then jump 20 ft. You could jump additional 10 ft if you wished, since the Jump spell allows you to and you have movement for it.

Depending on what is between you and the hound, you could run 20 ft and then jump 10 ft, without even using the Jump spell. If there is a gap of 30 ft or more, you would have to go back 10 ft, run 10 ft and then jump 30 ft, for a total of 50 ft of movement - which is still fine, since you have more than 50 ft of speed with the feature.

Essentially, both features are independent. **Jump increases how far you can jump, increasing the 10 to 30**, while your Speed tells you how far you can move - if you can't move any more, you can't jump as well, since jumping requires movement. I.e., if you had a speed of 30 ft, you wouldn't be able to do the run back, run towards and jump 30 ft, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all Tabitha wants to do is jump *onto* the hellhound, that's pretty straightforward, even without Feline Agility.

1. Tabitha moves 10 feet forward, to make a *long jump* (PHB 182)
2. Tabitha makes a long jump.
   (up to (Strength Score)*3) > 20 feet that remain between them, so no problems here.

If she wants to "get the jump on him" as in surprise him, technically I'm sure you're aware that neither of these skills help with stealth. You might feel like being able to jump *away* would help avoid an AoO though.

1. Tabitha moves 30 feet up to the hellhound
2. Tabitha Attacks the hellhound
3. With *feline agility* (VGtM 115) she still has 30 feet of movement
4. Tabitha jumps Str Score * 3 = 30 feet away.

However, you *would still trigger an attack of opportunity*:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach. [...] The attack interrupts the provoking creature's
>   movement, occurring right before the creature leaves your reach. You can avoid provoking an opportunity attack by taking the Disengage action. You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.

Nothing here says that if you're jumping it would help. You're still moving away.

If she wants to jump *over* him, she'll need that feline agility to give her the necessary movement, as jumps *do* cost the movement that they cover (PHB 182)

However, we also need to make sure she can get *over* the hellhound:

> At your DM's option, you must succeed on a DC 10 Strength (Athletics) check to clear a low obstacle (***no taller than a quarter of the jump's distance***) - PHB 182)

So that 30 foot long jump can be max 7.5 feet high. The hellhound is medium - he's unlikely to be less than 2.5 feet tall, so that's still in his melee range.

You *could* homebrew a hybrid jump; Perhaps the twice the number of feet you go up over this is subtracted from the distance you go across. In that case, with the ring Tabitha could do a hybrid jump that is (3+Strength Mod)*3 high, and (Strength Score*3) - (height-length/4) * 2 long - 9feet high, 25 feet long (rounded). Just enough to keep her out of the Hellhound's range, provided he's less than 5 feet tall. As a medium four legged creature, that seems *fairly* reasonable.

1. Tabitha moves 20 feet forward
2. Tabitha takes her jump at maximum with the ring: 9 feet high, 25 feet long
   This places her 10 feet beyond the hellhound - out of reach, and uses up 34 feet of movement she's only got 6 left, after the first 20, even with feline agility.
3. Tabitha moves a further 5(rounded) feet to make sure.

Of course, this relies on you using the Homebrew I suggested. Also note that with a movement speed of 50, the hellhound isn't going to have much trouble catching her on his turn...